# Do I need to pass 2 Models into this View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a page that displays a number of photos each rendered by a View `PhotoListItemView`. When the photo is clicked, a modal View `ModalAddToSetView` appears with a list of Sets `SetListView`. When one of the Set `SetView` is clicked, I need to send the `photo_id` and `set_id` to the backend.

**Problem:** In the click handler of the Set, I can easily get the `set_id` of the set clicked by using `this.model.get('id')`. What is the conventional way of getting the `photo_id`?

**View of Photo**

*`photo_id` is in the model passed to this view*

```
PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click #add.photo_btn' : 'add'
    },

    add: function(event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // Show modal
        $('#modal_addit').modal();
        modalAddToSetView = new ModalAddToSetView({ model: this.model });
    }

});
```

**View of Modal**

```
ModalAddToSetView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.renderSets();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    renderSets: function() {
        this.setList = new SetCollection();
        this.setListView = new SetListView({ collection: this.setList });
        this.setList.fetch({
            data: {user_id: $('#user_id').val()},
            processData: true
        });
    }
});
```

**View of Set**

```
SetListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(set, index) {
            $(this.el).append( new SetView({ model: set }).render().el );
        }, this);
    }
});

SetView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal_addit_set').html() ),

    events: {
        'click': 'addToSet'
    }

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    addToSet: function() {
        $.post('api/add_to_set', {
            photo_id: ,         // HOW DO I PASS THE PHOTO_ID?
            set_id: this.model.get('id')
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: beware with the instantiation of _global variables_ like this `modalAddToSetView = new ModalAdd...` ... remember to use `var` or you will find weird behaviors.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a var to all of them! I wonder if theres anywhere I can post my code and let people review it for oddities

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem passing the `photo_id` param to the `SetListView` constructor and passing it again to the `SetView` constructor:

```
// code simplified and no tested
SetListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function( opts ) {
    this.photo_id = opts.photo_id;
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(set, index) {
      $(this.el).append( new SetView({ model: set, photo_id: this.photo_id }).render().el );
    }, this);
  }
});

SetView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function( opts ) {
    this.photo_id = opts.photo_id;
  },

  addToSet: function() {
    $.post('api/add_to_set', {
      photo_id: this.photo_id,
      set_id: this.model.get('id')
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this is possible.

Comment: From the `opts` param any Backbone element constructor you can access to the hash passed to the constructor call. There are magic params as `collection`, `el`, `model` and so on that are taking automatically but there is not any problem to add your own ones. Actually I'm seeing [in the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) that the new Backbone is attaching all the constructor params to the `this.options` for future references.